# Java: how to evaluate list/array of futures

Tags: java, future

I have a use case of futures in a multinode application.

I'm using an Asynchronous Remoting library(Jgroups) to communicate between two nodes.
When I make an asynchronous call from one node to the other, i get back a future. and when the other node does some computation and returns, the future completes.

This is simple enough. 
But when I make 10,000 such remoting calls, I get back 10,000 futures.
What is the best way to find out when all of them complete ?

Use case: I'm trying to benchmark the performance(that includes remoting performance), and identify bottlenecks. I need to accurately timestamp when the futures complete. Using this, I can find trends by varying other parameters in my application.

To summarize:

- I have an array of upto 100,000 futures
- Need to know exact time of completion of each of the futures in that array.

Comment: You could use the get() method and when this call returns, you could store the time

Comment: This won't answer your question directly, but you could use [Guava's Futures.allAsList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...)) to generate a single aggregate future object to detect when all are finished, and you probably can use Guava to define some sort of callback that would store the appropriate time or give the timestamp as a result of the future.

Comment: Had a look at Guava's APIs before... They treat the entire list of futures as a single future.
meaning even if one of my futures fail (say because of a network timeout), then i get a single result, which would say failed.

Comment: I had a quick look at JGroups docs. It mentions something called `NotifyingFuture` which has a method to add a listener notifying when the result is available. Any reason you can't use that to fix your time?